# Connect to postgres database on local linux install

Tags: ruby, linux, postgresql, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to figure out how to connect via my ruby app using PGConn in order to connect to my postgres database on the aws ec2 linux server.

```
db_connection = PGconn.connect("ip-172-31-90.9.us-west-2.compute.internal", 5432, '', '', "testdb", "username", "password")
```

I keep getting an error

```
app.rb:21:in `initialize': could not translate host name "ip-172-31-90-9.us-west-2.compute.internal." to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

I ran /sbin/ifconfig -a on the linux server to get the IP address, but it still can't connect.  I also edited the files per the instructions from the site http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP of "ip-172-31-90-9" seems private IP address.

So what you need do:

1. assign public IP or Elastic IP to that ec2 instance.
2. set inbound rule in its security group and open the port 5432 to `0.0.0.0/0` or any IP ranges in your case
3. test the port from your local

   telnet NEW_Public_IP 5432

If can, then you should be fine to connect the database.

Comment: I tried this, but it still says connection refused.

Comment: I also ended up having to also make the changes per this document to get it to work.   http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html  Thanks for your help!